# Improvise SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the below sql which takes 1 or 2 secs to return the result. I am calling this SQL inside cursor for 500 plus times. I am trying to re-write this query.

```
SELECT Sum(CASE 
                WHEN UpdatedAdjustedOT IS NOT NULL
                    AND UpdatedAdjustedOT != ''
                    AND UpdatedAdjustedOT != '0'
                    THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), UpdatedAdjustedOT)
                ELSE 0
                END) AS OTHours
    FROM tbl_OTAuthorization
    WHERE EmployeeCodeFK = @EmployeeCode
        AND month(OTDate) = Month(@FromDate)
        AND year(OTDate) = Year(@FromDate)
```

Please suggest me how do I re-write this query in a better way

[image]

Comment: What's the outer query that's calling this one? This doesn't look that costly on it's own but if you're using it in a cursor then we'd need to see the outer query to understand what it's doing.

Comment: I have employeelist in cursor. I have to find othours by passing employeecode in this SQL

Comment: The problem is in your cursor so post _all_ the code and we can help

Comment: It looks like the CASE statement is unnecessary. Just `SUM(UpdatedAdjustedOT)` and add those conditions to your WHERE clause... `WHERE UpdatedAdjustedOT IS NOT NULL
                    AND UpdatedAdjustedOT != ''
                    AND UpdatedAdjustedOT != '0'`

Comment: I'd have an issue with using the cursor in the first place. Show us the code that calls the cursor and I bet there will be a better set based approach to get the same result.

Comment: The problem is there are lot of different table hits performed inside the cursor. I can't made a set based approach for now.

Comment: So you've asked the question of a very specific part of your code (which means you don't know how to fix it). More than one commenter have advised to post the outer code in the hope that we can find a better solution, but you know better? By the way, a set based approach would hit those tables once, not 500 + times as your cursor is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, re-write the `WHERE` clause to look like this:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM tbl_OTAuthorization
WHERE EmployeeCodeFK = @EmployeeCode AND
      OTDate >= DATEADD(day, 1 - DAY(@FromDate), @FromDate) AND
      OTDate < DATEADD(month, 1, DATEADD(@FromDate, 1 - DAY(@FromDate), @FromDate));
```

Second, create an appropriate index for the table:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_OTAuthorization_2 ON tbl_OTAuthorization(EmployeeCodeFK, OTDate, UpdatedAdjustedOT);
```

Third, go back and fix your code so it is not looping over employees and from dates.  You should be able to handle the logic in a single query.  In general, avoid cursors if you want to optimize the performance of using a database.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

Don't filter on function results.   Find a way to replace this:

```
AND month(OTDate) = Month(@FromDate)
AND year(OTDate) = Year(@FromDate)
```

to something like this:

```
 and OTDate >= the first day of the month for @FromDate
 and OTDate < the first day of the month following @FromDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Sum(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), ISNULL(NULLIF(UpdatedAdjustedOT, ''), 0))) as OTHours
    FROM tbl_OTAuthorization
    WHERE EmployeeCodeFK = @EmployeeCode
        AND month(OTDate) = Month(@FromDate)
        AND year(OTDate) = Year(@FromDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE EmployeeCodeFK = @EmployeeCode
    AND OTDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @FromDate), 0)
    AND OTDate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @FromDate), 0))
```